# Having issues connection motion sensor

Tags: electrical, switch, motion-sensor

I bought an in-wall PIR switch (http://amzn.to/293hYyJ) and I'm trying to install it. The switch has 4 wires: `red`, `black`, `white` and `green`

[image]

In my wall, I had 2 black wires and a green one that were connected to the original switch. There was also a white wire (2 actually) that were simply capped. So I connected it similar to this and now, the switch works if I put it in the `on` position, but not the motion detection part. How can I find out what the issue is?

Comment: Is it not turning on, not turning off, shooting laser beams? When the sensor is set to AUTO, what happens? Have you read the manual, and configured the sensor properly (if applicable)?

Comment: Are you certain the Neutral connections are solid?  Are you certain you connected Red to Load (i.e. towards the light) and Black to the Hot, and not vice versa?

Comment: I suspect you have Hot & Load reversed.